# inline script append multiple value to url issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html below where I want to append the value of the anchor tag "First" and the value of the div class "Second" to the url. In other word, upon clicking the anchor tag the url should be equal to your-order.php?key=Text&status=Second The inline script below somehow doesn't work. How can I get this right?

```
<a href="your-order.php?key=" onclick="return this.href += $.trim($(this).text()) + &status=$(.second).text());>First</a>
<div class="second">Second</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didnt try this code nor have I done an inline string concatenation run before but you can use concat to concatenate strings. Try this:

```
<a href="your-order.php?key=" onclick="return this.href.concat($.trim$(this).text(), ['&status=', $(.second).text()]);>First</a>
<div class="second">Second</div>
```